# Text field not responding

Tags: ios4, keyboard

I'm quite new to cocoa touch and have been playing around with it for a few days now. I'm testing some examples from Apress book on simulator and one of it requires to create textfield. The problem is, textfield is not responding at all and doesn't show up keyboard as a result. Anyone know what could be the culprit? I've checked "User interaction enable" and it is checked.

OS = snow leopard
ios = 4.2

Edit : Not just textbox, all controls don't respond at all.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I've just found out the culprit. Although I set "User Interaction enabled" of all the controls, I've missed the one from "view" object itself. Hope this help to whoever have the same problem.

Comment: I edited the title of the question to give any future person a shot at finding this. Yes, connecting the main `.view` property is important, and easily overlooked!